Finding $\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$ for a SDE
I have the following SDE:
$$dX_t=aX_tdt+bdW_t$$
I wanted to find $dX^2_t$ and from that I can get $d\mathbb{E}(X^2_t)$, from which i got:
$$dX^2_t=(2aX^2_t+b^2)dt+2bX_tdW_t$$
And taking expectation (going through the integral from of the ODE)
$$d\mathbb{E}(X^2_t)=(2a\mathbb{E}(X^2_t)+b^2)dt$$
From where the solution is $\mathbb{E}(X^2_t)=c_1e^{2at}-\frac{b^2}{2a}$, would this be correct? From searching around i found a slightly different solution still both seemed a little odd.

Your expression for $dX_t^2$ looks wrong. I get
\begin{align}
dX^2_t&=2X_t,dX_t+d\langle X,X\rangle_t=2X_t,(aX_t,dt+b,dW_t)+b^2,dt\
&=(2aX^2_t+b^2),dt+2b,\color{red}{X_t},dW_t,.
\end{align}

@KurtG. typo, doesnt change anything still

Apply Ito's Formula to to get that
\begin{align}X_{t}^{2}&=X_{0}^{2}+\int_{0}^{t}2X_{s}\,dX_{s}+\int_{0}^{t}b^{2}\,ds\\&=X_{0}^{2}+\int_{0}^{t}2aX_{s}^{2}\,ds+\int_{0}^{t}2bX_{s}\,dW_{s}+tb^{2}\end{align}
Thus, taking Expectation on both sides, noting that $E(\int_{0}^{t}2bX_{s}\,dW_{s})=0$ as it's a Martingale and using Fubini's Theorem, you get:-
$$E(X_{t}^{2})=E(X_{0}^{2})+\int_{0}^{t}2aE(X_{s}^{2})\,ds+tb^{2}$$
Let $E(X_{t}^{2})=f(t)$. This tells you that,
$$f(t)=E(X_{0}^{2})+\int_{0}^{t}2af(s)\,ds+tb^{2}$$
This gives you the ODE $f'(t)=2af(t)+b^{2}$, $f(0)=E(X_{0}^{2})$ and the solution to this ODE is given by
$$f(t)=E(X_{0}^{2})e^{2at}-\frac{b^{2}}{2a}(1-e^{2at})$$
You can also see my answer here for an alternative approach.

Thats what i got indeed, but my issue is that such would imply that variance grows when a grows which to me seems a little odd, wouldnt making the deterministic part have a greater weight make it so that the noise has less of an effect? I'm probably missing something or not seeing something.

@burneraccacc I don't understand what exactly your confusion is. The ODE itself should say to you that the rate of increase in variance increases with $a$. Also what exactly is deterministic about $X_{t},dt$? or $b,dW_{t}$. They both are completely random. The first one being an finite variation random process and the second one being a continuous martingale.  I don't understand what kind of heuristic you are using or learning that says that certain parts of a process are likely to have greater effect on the variance.

What im calling deterministic is the dt term, basically $dX_t=aX_tdt$ would be a deterministic ODE and u are then adding a certain noise $bdW_t$, maybe it is smth that I wrongly interpreted but to me it made sense that having a greater $a$ would in term imply that the behaviour for $X_t$ would more closely match the ODE written above but ig its just a missconception I had

@Mr. Gandalf Sauron: I followed what you did except for the very first step where you say applying Ito's Lemma. Thanks and I'm sorry for my bad question.

@markleeds What is it that is confusing you? I am applying Ito's Lemma verbatim. If $X$ is a continuous semi martingale,  then for $F\in C^{2}(\Bbb{R})$, you have $F(X_{t})=F(X_{0})+\int_{0}^{t}F'(X_{s}),dX_{s}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}F''(X_{s}),d\langle X,X\rangle_{s}$. In case you are not familiar with this general form, then just apply Ito's formula verbatim  for Ito Processes of the $dX_{t}=\mu_{t},dt+\sigma_{t},dB_{t}$ as it appears in Wikipedia. Btw, here $F(x)=x^{2}$.

@Mr. Gandalf Sauron Gotcha. I see what you did now. Thanks a lot for your help.
